# ThreeJS object is in view?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

In my ThreeJS app the view swings to center on an object if that object is close to the centre of view (and the object is closer than a predetermined amount). I know the lat/lon of all the objects and of the viewer (camera). However, I don't know if there's another object in the way like a wall.

Is there a way to have ThreeJS tell me if that object is viewable from the camera?

This answer seemed like a good way except its for an earlier version of ThreeJS and I can't find the equivalent of webglObjects array in later versions: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3627#issuecomment-20763458

ThreeJS Frustum culling doesn't seem to be the answer because it only tells me if the camera is pointed in the right direction, not if the view of the object is blocked.

Raycaster solutions aren't good because the target object isn't a point, its wide and tall.

Implementing my own occlusion culling seems to be beyond what I'm capable of unless there's a sample somewhere (that I cannot find).

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code you linked to will not help. Three.js performs simple frustum culling on it's objects, it doesn't do manual occlusion culling. That's what the z-buffer is for.

Comment: A practical way to tackle this (depending on your exact requirements) is to keep looking into Raycaster-based solutions: cast multiple rays (not just to the center) to get a reasonable estimate of whether your target object is obscured or not.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll do. I'll try to cast rays from the object back to the camera (which *is* a point).

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've coded a solution with the caveat that it considers the view of an object is blocked if the camera can't see its point of origin. Critiques welcome! I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
// Returns true if a named object blocks the view of the origin point of the target object
// threeScene and threeCamera are defined elsewhere as:
// threeScene = new THREE.Scene();
// threeScene.add(mesh);
// ...
// threeCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...
// ...
var objectViewBlocked = function(objectName) {
  if (threeScene) {
    var object = threeScene.getObjectByName(objectName);
    if (object) {
      var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
      direction.subVectors(object.position, threeCamera.position); // Subtracting two vectors gives a direction vector to one from another
      direction.normalize();                                       // THREE.Raycaster() requires a normalized direction vector
      var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(threeCamera.position, direction);
      var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(threeScene.children, false); // Get list of objects that intersect the ray
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        for (j=0; j<intersects.length; j++) {
          if ((intersects[j].object !== undefined) && (intersects[j].object['name'] !== objectName) && (intersects[j].object['name'] !== '')) {
            // Ray intersects an object other than the target object and nameless objects
            return true;
          }
        }
      }

      // The ray intersects only the target object and nameless objects (i.e. the grid on the floor, etc.) but nothing that occludes it
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Scene is null or can't get object
  return true;
};
```